# Cross-platform File sync tool

Tags: windows, linux, file, synchronization, backup

I am developing a webapp that will be used on LAN mostly. I have different locations where I deployed this app. Some of the locations run windows and some run linux (no x-window system). I need to know if there is a software out there that could easily synchronize my files stored somehere in the cloud (the clouding service can be provided by the app developers or to use different clouds) on both linux and windows machines. My english is a bit rusty so i'm going to explain this in simple words.

I will work on my local machine. I want to upload the files somewhere on the cloud and the clients installed on the LAN servers should synchronize the files. The client must be available for linux under console (as a daemon if possible) while on windows it can be something like dropbox or ubuntu one.

Does somebody know of such an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox is available for Linux.

You could also investigate [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Comment: unison is not what i need but i found out that dropbox has a console version as well. i will mark you answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think "Git" is the best solution to develop your project in different machine.
You can sync your code with easy command through this app, and it will record all the version of your code.
Just google "Git tutorial", and you will find many useful introductions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a great tool called Syncthing should be considered after 8 years.

- https://syncthing.net/

> Syncthing is a continuous file synchronization program. It synchronizes files between two or more computers and replaces proprietary sync and cloud services with something open, trustworthy and decentralized. Your data is your data alone and you deserve to choose where it is stored, if it is shared with some third party and how it's transmitted over the internet.
>   Check the list of Syncthing's goals for more details.